# Arel node for an array element (suffix operator)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, arel

Is there any arel node for suffix operators to access array elements like this:

```
column = Table.arel_table[:column]
low = here_magic_happens(column, '[1]')
Table.where(low.eq nil).or(Table.where(low.gt 5))
# should result in this where clause:
# "table"."column"[1] IS NULL OR "table"."column"[1] > 5
```

Comment: Your column data type is an *array* ?

Comment: Yes, postgresql's `integer[]` .

Answer (score 0):

After 5 years, I haven't found anything better than this yet:

```rb
low =  Arel.sql("column[#{index}]")
Table.where(low.eq nil).or(Table.where(low.gt 5))
```